# Turning off registration / login in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I am wondering if it's possible to somehow in Magento CE 1.9+ to turn off registration, login and checkout possibility in an easy kind of way.

I have a webshop where we want to start out by simple showing off product and having it as a gateway into our store. But we will later (in a year or so) move into selling straight from the webshop.

So it would be great if there was a extension / way of doing a module myself that could simple turn on / turn off these kinds of features so that when we're ready to start selling products straight from the website, enable registration/login/checkout again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off registration can be done in a simple custom module. There is an event `customer_registration_is_allowed`.

An observer for this event could look like this:

#### Observer

```
public function disallowRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getResult()->setIsAllowed(false);
}
```

This turns off registration but not login. So you need to hide any links that go to the login page in your theme. You could to this conditionally based on the result of the observer above:

#### Templates

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()): ?>
    ... login ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How do I actually add that Observer? I'm not all that technical yet on modules. Just starting to learn. :)

Comment: This should help you: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/

Answer (score 0):

Need to change some bult in settings. Here are some steps should help you.

1. Got to `System->Configuration->Advanced` and disable the **Mage_Customer** and **Mage_Checkout** modules.
2. Got to `System->Configuration->Inventory` expand the **Stock Options** and **Product Stock Options** sections. then change value of
   **Display Out of Stock Products** to **Yes**,
   **Display products availability in stock in the frontend** to **No**,
   **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** to **100000**
3. Reindex your store from `System->Index Management`.

Comment: What more does Mage_Customer shutoff den? This seem to be a good solution otherwise.